# If Malloc Fails To Alloc X Bytes Do I Use Realloc Or Use Malloc Again? C++

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, memory-management

I've been reading a book on C++ memory management, it has a'lot of details and explains things very well. However I have a program I've been working on, it has to handle some really big vectors or arrays.
I'm confused though. I decided I would try to alloc memory just in-case.

My question is, if I try to `malloc()` a certain amount of data, and something goes wrong. If I want to try to preform the `malloc()` again and allocate less data, do I use `realloc()` or do I use `malloc()` again? I think it sounds like a stupid question however since the first `malloc()` would fail, wouldn't it not get malloced at all... ??? Meaning you should be able to still use `malloc()` on it?

So... which do I use, or do I use none of the following at all?

```
BYTE *allocptr;
allocptr = (BYTE*)malloc(2500000);
if (!allocArray)
{
    allocptr = (BYTE*)malloc(1000000);
} 
// program code
free(allocptr);
```

Or should I use `realloc()` to try a smaller amount of bytes...
instead of trying `malloc()` again if the first `malloc()` fails?

```
BYTE *allocptr;
allocptr = (BYTE*)malloc(2500000);
if (!allocptr)
{
    allocptr = (BYTE*)realloc(allocptr, 1000000);
} 
// program code
free(allocptr);
```

The reason why I'm asking this question is because if the first `malloc()` fails to allocate 2,500,000 bytes wouldn't the allocptr equal NULL... If allocptr was equal to NULL couldn't I use `malloc()` on it instead of `realloc()` on it because I thought `realloc()` can't take a pointer that equals NULL.

Comment: You seem to be confused about what [realloc](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/realloc/) does. You can't change the size of an memory-block if you never got one.

Comment: @tkausl Yes, I read that in the book I was reading that addressed the fact that you cant realloc pointers that equal NULL or something like that, thanks for the help that pretty much answers the question.

Comment: `realloc` takes 2 parameters (a pointer and a size) so your code wouldn't work.

Comment: @JohnnyMopp Oh I didn't even notice that, I just typed it in without copying it from my code. Thanks. I will edit it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Realloc changes the size of an allocated block or memory (or allocates a new one and copies the old content over). You use this when you, for example, allocated 5 bytes of memory, and later notice, that you need 5 more bytes.

In your case, where `malloc` failed, you never *got* any block of memory to begin with, so there is nothing to reallocate, so you'd use `malloc`.

Note: As @DavidSchwarz mentioned, you *can* use realloc, but this is equivalent to calling malloc if the first parameter is NULL.

Comment: You actually didn't answer the question though. The answer is that he can use either `malloc` or `realloc` since both of them can be used to allocate a new block of memory.

Answer (score 0):

There are two things going on here.  The first concerns the behavior of a failed `malloc()`.  `malloc()` either works, and returns a pointer to the memory block, or fails to allocate the memory, and returns a null pointer.  (Note that in the second case no memory is allocated, as opposed to, say, "doing its best" and allocating some value less than the amount asked for.)

The second is the possible similarity between realloc and malloc in error cases. 
 `realloc()` takes, amongst other things, a pointer to the memory block previously allocated by `malloc()`.  However, if the pointer happens to be `null`, then `realloc()` works exactly the same as `malloc()`, and a new block is allocated. (And if the `realloc()` call should fail, the return is a null pointer, just like `malloc()`.)

References: [c++ malloc](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/malloc/), [c++ realloc](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/realloc/)